# How do I make a schema with objects in array? Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

How to make a Schema of this document (instead of "0" in the users array, there will be a random number):

```
[
    {
        "idclient": 0,
        "users": {
            "0": {
                "id": 192,
                "uid": 12,
                "level": 3
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in a JSON file, array is declared by `[]`

You can check the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays)

So your schema has to be

```
[
    {
        "idclient": 0,
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 192,
                "uid": 12,
                "level": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

If it not exists `[]` that's not an array.